# Programmatically auto select an Excel table in Visual Basic in an Add-In

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2013

When using Excel, pressing CTRL+* (asterisk) when the cursor is inside a table, automatically identifies the table and selects it.

Is there a way to do exactly that when writing an Excel add-in in Visual Basic using Visual Studio 2013?

Answer (score 0):

Use  the Macro Recorder to generate the equivalent VBA object model calls: that should give you enough information to identify the VB.NET Interop calls.

(Using the Macro recorder in this way saves hours of trying to work things out from the documentation)

In this case you get

Selection.CurrentRegion.Select

Comment: Thanks Charles.

I already tried that :)

Thing is, it won't work from the Add-In code written in Visual Studio.
I guess I'm missing the correct object path to make it work from the external Add-In?

Thanks!

Comment: What error message did you get? Would help if you show what code you have tried: presumably you replaced Selection with the appropriately qualified object.

Comment: Hi Charles. My command:
Dim activeWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet = CType(Application.ActiveSheet, Excel.Worksheet)

Dim currentCell As Excel.Range = Me.Application.ActiveCell

Dim table_All As Excel.Range = activeWorksheet.Range(currentCell).CurrentRegion.Select()

The third line throws this error:

An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in MorTest1.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Thanks!